# OSX Multiple toolbars in NSTabViewController

Tags: xcode, macos

I have a structure which is represented in the picture below (sorry but apparently in OS Sierra Xcode does not support anymore zooming in the storyboard -.- ) 
`Window > TabController > View Controllers`

[image]

Basically what I wanted to do is to have multiple toolbars, each one for a different `ViewControllers`. If I were on iOS I could have set a `UINavigationController` as target of the `TabViewController` and then do whatever I wanted with the related navigation bar, but here in OSX I cannot link the `TabViewController` to a `WindowController` (which handles the toolbar), hence having a `window controller` per `view controller`. 
Is there any simple workaround for that?  
 
Or the only solution is to empty-refill the toolbar with the correct buttons every time a Tab is selected?

Comment: If you change the toolbar, the controls in the toolbar (= outside the tabview) will change when the user switches tabs. This will confuse the user. Don't do it.